# Symfony LDAP Authentication and MySQL user provider

Tags: symfony, authentication

I am trying to use the following:

1) form_login_ldap just for user authentification

2) A custom UserProvider for retrieving user roles from a MySQL database

Everything seems to work fine: I am able to login, the roles are used etc.
As soon as I change the roles in the database, `isEqualTo()` kicks in - the user is redirected to the login page. There the browser hangs in an endless loop. After using tcpdump I realized that form_login_ldap is trying to authenticate the user without a password.

I think I am generally missing the point how the password will be handled in this scenario. My UserProvider can't retrieve an (encrypted) password as he is querying MySQL and the user is authenticated using LDAP.
If the "refreshUser function of my UserProvider returns a new user object with the new roles, the password seems to be lost.
If within the UserProvider i just modify the array of roles for the user, the web application does not recognize that and old roles apply (I guess the session must be updated?).

How are form_login_ldap and my UserProvider supposed to interact? How do I make sure that upon "refreshUser" the password is still available?

What am I missing for my general picture?